# Adding a syscall with arguments to FreeBSD kernel

Tags: kernel, freebsd, system-calls

I want to add a system call using KLD in FreeBSD 8.2 that has some arguments (1 argument here)
I've done the following (I've actually changed the the syscall.c in /usr/share/examples/kld/syscalls/module/syscall.c)

```
#include <sys/param.h>
#include <sys/proc.h>
#include <sys/module.h>
#include <sys/sysproto.h>
#include <sys/sysent.h>
#include <sys/kernel.h>
#include <sys/systm.h>

struct hellomet_args{
    int a;
};

static int
hellomet(struct thread *td, struct hellomet_args *arg)
{
    int a = arg->a;

    printf("hello secondish kernel %d  \n",a);
    return (0);
}

static struct sysent hellomet_sysent = {
    1,          
    hellomet            
};




static int offset = NO_SYSCALL;


static int
load(struct module *module, int cmd, void *arg)
{
    int error = 0;

    switch (cmd) {
    case MOD_LOAD :
        printf("syscall loaded at %d\n", offset);
        break;
    case MOD_UNLOAD :
        printf("syscall unloaded from %d\n", offset);
        break;
    default :
        error = EOPNOTSUPP;
        break;
    }
    return (error);
}

SYSCALL_MODULE(hellomet, &offset, &hellomet_sysent, load, NULL);
```

When I make this file using provided Makefile in module directory I get :

```
cc1: warnings being treated as errors syscall.c:56: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type
*** Error code 1

Stop in /usr/share/examples/kld/syscall/module.
*** Error code 1
```

What's the problem with this code?

Comment: What is `syscall.c:56` ? FreeBSD compiles stuff with `-Werror` so warning like that are treated as errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are initialising the `sy_call` member of `hellomet_sysent` with a function pointer that doesn't match the typedef. `sy_call` is of type `sy_call_t`, which is defined as being a function that takes `(struct thread* , void*)` and returns `int`. Your call takes `(struct thread*, struct hellomet_args *)` instead.

Try something like this:

```
static struct sysent hellomet_sysent = {
    1,          
    (sy_call_t*) hellomet            
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your syscall's signature from

```c
static int
hellomet(struct thread *td, struct hellomet_args *arg)
```

to

```c
static int
hellomet(struct thread *td, void *arg)
```

and then, in syscall's body

```c
...
struct hellomet_args *uap;
uap = (struct hellomet_args *)arg;
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also add

```
NO_WERROR=
```

into your Makefile.